login with google in nextjs with next-auth using google provider in FE with express backend using passport js ( passport-google-oauth20 stategy )
I am building a MERN app where FE is in Nextjs and BE express.
I have integrated passport js authentication ( i.e passport-local and passport-jwt) in backend which works fine for credentialsProvider in next-auth but I  want to integrate login with google. I have integrated passport-google-oauth20 in server side which would worked fine if nextjs wasn't used, since there is google provider in nextjs. I don't know what should be standard approach in this condition. Which is the best way to implement login with google in nextjs with next auth with express server ?
I tried multiple ways, but I implemented one way, i.e I am using google provider from next auth, retrieving all data in signIn callback and calling a endpoint which is specific for google, which takes user data but not password, and this google endpoint business logic is if the user is found then return user, else create and return user
